# Why does fifelse() throw an error while ifelse() does not?

Tags: r, data.table

In example below, get an error msg. (mismatch data type) when using fifelse whereas ifelse works just fine.

```
DT = data.table(
  ID = c("b","b", "b", "a", "a", "c"),
  a = 1:6,
  b = c(7, 7, 9, 9, 11, 11)
)

DT[, d := fifelse(b - a > 5, b -a, NA)]
```

Error in fifelse(b - a > 5, b - a, NA) : 
'yes' is of type double but 'no' is of type logical. Please make sure that both arguments have  the same type.

However,

```
DT[, d := ifelse(b - a > 5, b -a, NA)]
DT
```

Works Just fine
ID a  b  d
1:  b 1  7  6
2:  b 2  7 NA
3:  b 3  9  6
4:  a 4  9 NA
5:  a 5 11  6
6:  c 6 11 NA

Have been using fifelse extensively lately but, this behavior is definitely unexpected.

Comment: Read the documentation for `fifelse`.  Particularly the __Arguments__ section for `yes, no`

Comment: did you see this? `'yes' is of type double but 'no' is of type logical. Please make sure that both arguments have the same type` have you tried replacing `NA` with `NA_real_`?

Comment: Another way to frame this is that `ifelse` is *failing you* by allowing you to specify different classes of objects in the `yes=` and `no=` arguments. Harsh words, yes, but the point is that since `ifelse` returns a vector, and a vector (in R) must always be the same class, then all objects in both vectors must be the same class. Oh, and R has many different types of `NA`, including logical, integer, numeric, character, even posix and date, all are different classes.

Comment: `lapply(list(NA, NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_character_, Sys.Date()[NA], Sys.time()[NA]), class)`

Comment: Both `data.table::fifelse` and `dplyr::if_else` are more careful about this, erring when you are potentially changing class (they are more "type-safe" in this regards, R is often not type-safe due to its easy auto-coersion).

Comment: This is related https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4287

Answer (score 0):

Since with `fifelse` we are operating in the `data.table`-environment with fixed data types per column, the input for the `na`-argument [has to be of the same type](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.8/topics/fifelse) as the `yes` and `no` arguments, even if it is `NA`. There are special `NA`-types to define just that, such as `NA_character_`, `NA_real_`, `NA_integer_` and so on.

In your case the `yes` and `no` arguments are of the type `integer`, the standard `NA`, however, is of the type `logical`. This means, the correct input to your `NA`-argument is `NA_integer_`. That way every output of the fifelse-clause is of the same type and can be used as a column within a `data.table`.

A base R `ifelse`-clause will not throw this error, since it does not assume you are working within the `data.table`-environment. Therefore it is okay to output different data-types, as the integrity of a fixed data type column would not be jeopardized.